# Files sent through form with multipart/form-data are sent as empty object

Tags: javascript, file, express, vue.js, multipartform-data

I'm creating a VueJS component that is a form that asks user's information and also allows multiple image uploads.

The form has enctype="multipart/form-data" and looks like this :

```
<template>
  <div>        
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="surname">
        <label> Description </label>
        <input type="text" v-model="description">        
        <input 
         type="file"
         id="resources"
         ref="images"
         multiple 
         @change="handleFileUpload()"
         accept="image/*">   

    <button @click="clear">Clear Form</button>
     <button @click="submit"> Submit  </button>
        </div>
      </form>
 </template>
```

My function handleFileUpload() does this :

```
this.images = this.$refs.images.files
```

My submit function looks like this :

```
submit ()  {
// Saves image to formData 
let formData = new FormData()

for( var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++ ){
   let img = this.images[i];
   formData.append('image[' + i + ']', img);
}

let newUser = {
  name : this.name,
  surname:this.surname,
  description : this.description,
  images : formData
}

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', newUser)
 .then(()=>{console.log('ok')})
 .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
}
```

My problem is that the images field from newUser is being sent as an empty object. I'm not sure if I should send formData like that or there's some problem with the express API i have built for this :

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());


let users = [],

app.post('/api/users',(req,res) => {
  const newUser = req.body
  users.push(newUser)
  res.json(users)
}
```

A console.log of newUser in the API  returns this :

```
{ name: 'test',      
  surname: 'test',
  description: 'test',
  images: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The body-parser module does not support multipart/form-data as it says in their documentation (this can be hard to figure out if you're new to nodejs).

You will need to find some middleware that will handle this for you. [The body-parser documentation recommends a few](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> - [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy#readme)
> - [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
> - [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#readme)
> - [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme)

Each library will work slightly differently, so you should use their documentation to construct your `images` object on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling also with *empty request body* in my api server project. 
I wanted to post multipart-form data which consists of string/text data and an image to a backend restful api server. I  thought that by just passing the data using formData object through Axios would be sufficient. However I ended up almost frustated because in the backend restful api project I kept getting empty request body. Thankfully through search on some articles, stackoverflow and youtube. I managed to assemble a fully working node.js program. No more empty request body data !!! . 
Here I would like to share my working codes.

To pass multipart/form-data from client to server, I have found out that we to use several middlewares and node/java objects :

- In the server side api project : I use *{multer, body-parser}* middlewares
- In the client app project : I use *formData and axios*

Here are my working codes : ( coded in node.js ,  using visual studio code)

```
// in my (server backend api) node project :  /src/routes/products/index.js

const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const ProductsController = require('../controllers/products')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    // use this on Windows dir
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname)
    // otherwise (in Linux or IOS use this
    // cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
  }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
// reject a file if not allowed
var allowedMimes = ['image/jpeg','image/png' , 'image/gif']
if (allowedMimes.indexOf(file.mimetype) > -1) {
  cb(null, true)
  } else {
  cb(null, false)
  }   
}

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10},
  fileFilter: fileFilter
})

router.post("/", upload.single('productImage'),ProductsController.products_create_product)

module.exports = router

// end of  /src/routes/products/index.js
```

Now in (server backend api) /src/app.js :

```
const express = require("express")
const morgan = require("morgan")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const productRoutes = require("./routes/products")

const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shopcart', {
  useMongoClient: true
})

var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log("Connected to mongoDB..."+ db.db.databaseName+ ', url: ' +'http://localhost:5000')
})

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

app.use(morgan("dev"))
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  )
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET")
    return res.status(200).json({})
  }
  next()
})

// Routes which should handle requests
app.use("/products", productRoutes)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("api Not found...")
  error.status = 404
  next(error)
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500)
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  })
})

module.exports = app
//end of : /src/app.js
```

Now in (server backend api) /src/index.js :

```
const http = require('http')
const app = require('./app.js')

const ip_addr = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(port , ip_addr)
console.log('Server started on %s port: %s',ip_addr , port )

// end of : /src/index.js
```

Code for ProductController in (backend api) : /src/controller/Products.js :
(please note that the req.file is automatically added by 'multer' middleware)

```
exports.products_create_product = (req, res, next) => {
  // note : productImage: req.file.path
  //        (file) is added by 'multer' middleware 
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    specification: req.body.specification,
    productImage: req.file.path
  })

  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Product created successfully",
        createdProduct: {
          name: result.name,
          price: result.price,
          specification: result.specification,
          _id: result._id,
          productImage: result.productImage,
          request: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/products/"  
          }
        }
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      })
    })
}
```

And finally in **my client app project**, I use **Axios** and **formData** to send post request to the backend api server.

Here is the code extract for Front end client app to post:

```
  function createProduct (payload, apiUrl, myAuthToken) {

  const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      // 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myAuthToken // if using JWT 
  }
  var formData = new FormData()

  formData.append( 'productImage', payload.productImage)
  formData.append( 'name', payload.name)
  formData.append( 'price', payload.price)
  formData.append( 'specification', payload.specification)

  Axios.post(apiUrl + '/products',  
   formData,
    {'headers' : headers} 
  )
    .then((response) => {

      var imgUrl = response.data.createdProduct.productImage
      payload.productImage = apiUrl+'/'+ imgUrl.replace(/\\/g, "/")
      payload.id= response.data.createdProduct._id
      payload.specification = response.data.createdProduct.specification
      payload.price =response.data.createdProduct.price
      commit('createProduct', payload)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error)
    })
}
```

The following function can be used to extract image data from an input html event :

```
    function onFilePicked (event) {

    const files = event.target.files
    if (!files) {
      return
    }
    let filename = files[0].name
    if (filename.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) {
      return alert('Please add a valid file!')
    }
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.productImage = fileReader.result
    })
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0])

    return files[0]
  }
```

I hope these codes will help anybody running into empty request body problem.